# Theorem style similar to equation

Tags: theorems

I was trying to treat theorems and lemmas as in the book [Visual complex analysis](http://books.google.es/books?id=P-X1nQEACAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions) which in my opinion has a very nice format for informal reading.

I would like to have equations and propositions numbered in a single enumeration, both with the enumerator right justified in the right of the page as in the following examples taken from the book:

Example 1: you can have equations (or other constructs like enumerations) inside the propositions
[image]

Example 2: Propositions are justified while equations are centered.
[image]

I haven't arrived very far in my trials, my best so far only handles one line propositions as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
\begin{document}
  \noindent Some text
  \begin{equation}
     \text{\itshape One line proposition of text and math $f(x) = \sin x$.}
  \end{equation}
  some more text
  \begin{equation}
     f(x) = \sin x 
  \end{equation}
  some more text
  \begin{equation}
    \text{\itshape Long proposition of text don't fit in the page and continue past the         
           right margin.}
  \end{equation}
  some more text
 \end{document}
```

But this has a lot of problems: it doesn't handle multiline propositions, and it doesn't center equations to begin with. Could you give me some clue on how to obtain the style used in the book?

Comment: Off topic: Nice book!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another suggestion based on `tcolorbox`.

The `myproposition` environment is provided numbered and additionally unnumbered using a star. Both variants are breakable. The example code repeats the number, if the propositons gets broken. Just remove the `overlay middle and last` key, if you do not want that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,lipsum}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{proposition/.style={enhanced,breakable,fontupper=\itshape,
  frame hidden,interior hidden,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  left=25pt,right=25pt}}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=equation]{myproposition}[1][]{%
  proposition,
  overlay unbroken and first={\node[left,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
    at (frame.east) {(\thetcbcounter)};},
  overlay middle and last={\node[left,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,align=center]
    at (frame.east) {\textit{\footnotesize cont.}\\(\thetcbcounter)};},
  #1}

\newtcolorbox{myproposition*}[1][]{proposition,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{r_B}{r_A} = \sqrt{\rho}
\end{equation}

For our second application, recall that if two points on a sphere are
diametrically opposite to each other (such as the north and south poles) then
they are said to be antipodal. Let us show that
\begin{myproposition}[label={antipodal points}]
  If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
  stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
  \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
\end{myproposition}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{myproposition}[label={antipodal points 2}]
  This proposition is broken from one page to the next.
  If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
  stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
  \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
\end{myproposition}

\lipsum[4]

See something in Proposition~\ref{antipodal points}
or in Proposition~\ref{antipodal points 2}.

Now follows an unnumbered proposition.

\begin{myproposition*}
  If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
  stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
  \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
\end{myproposition*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Now, that's not very colorful, but you asked for a clean design. Nevertheless, I could not resist to add at least a variant with an ornamentic line. Here, the number for the broken proposition is not repeated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,lipsum}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{proposition/.style={enhanced,breakable,fontupper=\itshape,
  frame hidden,interior hidden,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  left=25pt,right=25pt,
  overlay={\draw[lightgray,line width=2pt]
    ([xshift=-1pt]frame.north east) -- ([xshift=-1pt]frame.south east);}}}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=equation]{myproposition}[1][]{%
  proposition,
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \node[left,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (N) at (frame.east) {(\thetcbcounter)};
    \draw[lightgray,line width=2pt]
      ([xshift=-1pt]frame.north east) |- ([yshift=2pt]N.north west)
      ([yshift=-2pt]N.south west) -| ([xshift=-1pt]frame.south east);},
  #1}

\newtcolorbox{myproposition*}[1][]{proposition,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{r_B}{r_A} = \sqrt{\rho}
\end{equation}

For our second application, recall that if two points on a sphere are
diametrically opposite to each other (such as the north and south poles) then
they are said to be antipodal. Let us show that
\begin{myproposition}[label={antipodal points}]
  If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
  stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
  \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
\end{myproposition}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{myproposition}[label={antipodal points 2}]
  This proposition is broken from one page to the next.
  If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
  stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
  \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
\end{myproposition}

\lipsum[4]

See something in Proposition~\ref{antipodal points}
or in Proposition~\ref{antipodal points 2}.

Now follows an unnumbered proposition.

\begin{myproposition*}
  If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
  stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
  \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
\end{myproposition*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suggestion similar to what you've already tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{myproposition}
  {\begin{equation}
   \begin{minipage}{0.90\linewidth}
     \itshape}
  {\end{minipage}%%
   \end{equation}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  For our second application, recall that if two points on a sphere are
  diametrically opposite to each other (such as the north and south poles) then
  they are said to be antipodal.  Let us show that
  \begin{myproposition}
    \label{antipodal points}
    If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are \emph{antipodal points} of $\Sigma$, then their
    stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following formula:
    \[ q = -(1/\bar p)\]
  \end{myproposition}
  \lipsum[1]
  See \ref{antipodal points}.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Your displayed equations were not being centered because you told `amsmath` to use `fleqn`.

I'm not entirely sure whether I like this approach I'm presenting here.
In particular, the `minipage` will not break across pages.  I suppose you could try something like `tcolorbox` which provides features such as breaking boxes across pages.  But then where should the number for the *proposition* or *theorem* go?  Are theorems and equations to be enumerated using the same counter?

Anyhow, consider this as a temporary suggestion until a better recommendation comes along.

**Equation numbering**

If you wanted to decouple the enumeration style of equations from your propositions, then you could do something like:

```
\newcounter{myequation}
\makeatletter
\def\my@incr@eqnum{\refstepcounter{myequation}\let\my@eqnum\@empty}
\newenvironment{myequation}{%
  \my@incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{myproposition}
  {\begin{myequation}
   \begin{minipage}{0.90\linewidth}
     \itshape}
  {\end{minipage}%%
   \end{myequation}}
```

Basically, this is the `amsmath` code used to redefine the `equation` environment hi-jacked to suite our needs here.  If this is a route you choose to take, then you'll probably want to fiddle with how the tags are displayed so that duplicate numbering won't create confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the solution is very clean and simple. It has the advantage of allowing the * version when there is no number and to use the same numbering scheme for a few lines of code (which is rather welcome). A pity it doesn't break accross pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here I adapted the `numberedblock` package, and created a macro `\proposition[]{}`.  The first optional argument is the label of the form `[\plabel{}]`, and the mandatory argument is the proposition content.

The `\numblock` macro adapted from `numberedblock` actually has its own counter, `blocknum`, which I slave to the `equation` counter.  If you changed your mind and wanted them numbered separately, they could be unslaved from each other, and the placement and format of the `blocknum` numbering could be altered to distinguish it from the `equation` numbering.

Note several configurable parameters that I have in this MWE made to mimic the `equation` environment.  They are lengths `\maxblocklabelsize` and `\blockindent`.  The former controls the label's horizontal location, and can be set negative to push the label outside the margin.  The latter is the left indent on the block.  Note that I have, through the use of the `\parbox` width, set up `\proposition` to provide symmetric indent on the right, corresponding to `\blockindent` on the left.  The last parameter to note is `\blocklabel`, which governs the appearance of the label at the right margin.

Propositions will **NOT** break across pages, because they are being set in a LaTeX box.

EDITED to make sure proposition equations were centered like normal equations.

REDITED to demonstrate support for `hyperref`, which must be loaded *before* `numberedblock`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{numberedblock}[2014/02/24]
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \setlength\maxblocklabelsize{.25in}
 \setlength\blockindent{0.3in}
 \renewcommand\blocklabel[1]{(\arabic{#1})}
 \let\plabel\nblabel
\newcommand\proposition[2][]{%
  \setcounter{blocknum}{\theequation}%
  \numblock{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\blockindent\relax}%
    {\rmfamily\itshape#2}#1}\newline%
  \stepcounter{equation}}
\begin{document}
In the beginning,
\begin{equation}
F = \frac{d}{dt} MV
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]
\proposition[\plabel{p:X}]{If $\hat p$ and $\hat q$ are antipodal points of $\Sigma$,
then their stereographic projections $p$ and $q$ are related by the following 
formula:

\centering\( q = -(1/\bar p).\)
}
In proposition~\ref{p:X}, \lipsum[5]
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having some problems which I don't quite understand, for some reason the whole block is beeing indented to the right as if it was beeing treated as character. I have tried several alternatives such as placing `\par\noindent` before the \numblock, but I haven't been able to make it work. There is also a problem with the hyperref package it doesn't allow me to place a \plabel in the first parameter.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi  As to the last problem, the `numberedblock` package was recently updated to handle labels.  You may need an update from http://ctan.org/pkg/numberedblock.  As to the indent, there is a parameter I set in the preamble, `\setlength\blockindent{0.3in}` which says that the proposition blocks should be indented by this amount.  Note though, that I set the `\parbox` width to be symmetrically indented on the right side, to achieve centering of the equations.  Making indent =0 on the left will cause the right end to overwrite the label on the right.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi Another point about `hyperref`, once you update `numberedblock` to the latest version.  Load `hyperref` *before* you load `numberedblock`.  I will update my MWE to show this.