# How to give some text an equation number

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath

I want to be able to  write the following in LaTeX

```
    We make the further assumption that
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:assumption} There is a bounded linear operator
    $B:X\to X^*$ such that $B^*=B$ and the operator $JB$ is an extension of $T'(0)$\end{equation}
```

and get a nice output, in such a way that this whole chunk of text along with the math can be referenced later. Of course I can write text inside the equation environment using `\text{}`, but when I tried this the spacing was all wrong. Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: some interesting options here: [Theorem style similar to equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170435/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  We make the further assumption that
  \begin{equation}\label{eqn:assumption}
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
    There is a bounded linear operator
    $B:X\to X^*$ such that $B^*=B$ and the operator $JB$ is an
    extension of $T'(0)$
    \end{minipage}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example (the value is only exemplary):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

We make the further assumption that
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:assumption} 
\text{\begin{tabular}{p{0.85\linewidth}}
There is a bounded linear operator
    $B\colon X\to X^*$ such that $B^*=B$ and the operator $JB$ is an extension of $T'(0)$
\end{tabular}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```