# How to create numbered/tagged statements?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

In LaTeX formulas can be automatically numbered like this:

```
\begin{equation}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  1+2=3
\end{equation}
```

This will produce something like that:

```
1+1=2                                   (1)
1+2=3                                   (2)
```

(Although the formulas will be centered.)

It is also possible to add a manual tag to replace the number and add a label to refer to the formula later:

```
\begin{equation} \tag{myTag} \label{myLabel}
  2+2=4 
\end{equation}
```

Which will look like this:

```
2+2=4                               (myTag)
```

However, this is only possible with math formulas. Is there also a way to make this type of formatting/numbering also work with ordinary text, i.e. short statements?

For example, it should look like this:

```
This is my statement.                   (3)
```

Comment: Is `\begin{equation} \mbox{This is my statement.} \end{equation}` acceptable?

Comment: @Mico Great! Although this doesn't work if the statement is more than one line long... Then it goes over the margin. Is there perhaps some way to support atomatic/manual line breaks?

Comment: @Mico I found a possibility to add manual line breaks: `\begin{align} &\mbox{My very long statement is continued}\\ &\mbox{in the second line.} \notag \end{align}` This should work. :) If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If you need a different numbering scheme than equations, you might see the `numberedblock` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202966/how-can-i-show-codeboxes/202969#202969 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170435/theorem-style-similar-to-equation/170449#170449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text-mode statement is short, i.e., if it fits comfortably within a single line, I'd suggest encasing the statement in an `\mbox` directive:

```
\begin{equation} 
  \mbox{This is my statement.} 
\end{equation}
```

In contrast, if there's a chance that your text-mode statement will span two or more lines, I'd suggest using a `\parbox` directive to house the text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text
\usepackage{showframe} % show frame lines around text block
% create a bespoke macro:
\newcommand\textbox[1]{\parbox{0.75\textwidth}{\raggedright #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \textbox{\lipsum[1][1-4]}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! :)